# Redirect in Play after POST Request to Play 2.3.x

Tags: scala, playframework

I am new to play. I have a scenario like I need to redirect the request that I am getting to other url.

Can anyone help with sample code snippets with play apis that can be added in controllers class?

Comment: See "Redirects are simple results too" in the docs https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaActions.

Comment: Read the documentation that Roman pointed to or refine your question

Answer (score 2):

To redirect to the index page use this:

```
Redirect(routes.Application.index)
```

Complete Example:

```
def foo() = Action {
   // handle your post-request stuff here....

   // Forward to index page (or somewhere else...)
   Redirect(routes.Application.index) 
}
```